# HTTPS redirect for directory doesn't work correctly

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

My goal is to force HTTPS on the `admin` directory of my site. However, using the usual way give an unusual result. Here is the content of `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} admin
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com/admin/$1 [R,L]
```

However, when I try to open `http://www.domain.com/admin/home.php`, instead of redirecting to `https://www.domain.com/admin/home.php` it sends me to `https://www.domain.com/admin/admin/home.php`.

So it sort of creates the `admin/` part of the URL twice.

I tried changing the last line of `.htaccess` to `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com/$1 [R,L]` (which doesn't make sense to me, but tried it still) and it redirected to the same wrong URL, which confused me further.

I'm not sure if it should matter, but I've also tried replacing `[R,L]` with `[L,R=301]` as suggested elsewhere on SO, with no avail.

Why is this happening and what's the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is due to `/admin/` in your target URL. Change your rule to this:

```
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^admin(/.*)?$ https://www.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L,NC]
```